# Prove that a function is differentiable at a point $c \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval, $c \in I,$ and suppose that $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $I$ and differentiable
every point $x \in I \backslash\{c\} .$

Prove that if $\lim _{x \rightarrow c} f^{\prime}(x)=L \in \mathbb{R},$ then $f$ is also differentiable at $c$ and $f^{\prime}(c)=L$

Idea: I want to show $\lim _{x \rightarrow c} f^{\prime}(x)$ = $f^{\prime}(c)$ which implies that $f^{\prime}(x)$ is continuous, but I don't know how to show this.

Comment: You can use The l'Hopital theorem to show that $f'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(c+h)}{1}$

Comment: @GabrieleCassese You should this into an answer. It's nice and elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We wish to show that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c + h) - f(c)}{h} = L.$$
Equivalently, using sequences, for every $h_n \to 0$ with $h_n \neq 0$, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(c + h_n) - f(c)}{h_n} = L.$$
Fix a sequence $h_n \to 0$ and $h_n \neq 0$. Note that the Mean Value Theorem shows us that there exists some $c_n$, lying between $c + h_n$ and $c$, such that
$$f'(c_n) = \frac{f(c + h_n) - f(c)}{h_n}.$$
By the squeeze theorem, $c_n \to c$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $\lim_{x \to c} f'(c) = L$, we have $f'(c_n) \to L$. Thus,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(c + h_n) - f(c)}{h_n} = L$$
as required.

Answer (score 1):

$f'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$

You can now apply [De L'Hopital theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule?wprov=sfla1) (differentiating on h) to obtain

$f'(c)=\lim_{h\to 0}f'(c+h)=\lim_{x\to c} f'(x)$